# C# - Parse JSON Asynchronously into Objects and add to queue for further processing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to preform ETL like operations onto a JSON file that I receive inside of a .tar.gz. I have been able to successfully unzip and untar the file into a memory stream.

My issue is this, these files are so large that I see memory issues when trying to use various libraries to parse the file into objects. I have used suggestions from a few places to try not to read the whole file but they still involve throwing the whole file into memory it would seem.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

What I would like to do, is asynchronously read a lite bit of the file, try to parse this read into objects, and then add to the appropriate queues for further processing. My hope is that I can strip these objects out of memory as quickly as possible.

**Example JSON**

```
{
  "header" : {
    "id" : 12345,
    "datetime" : 1640423287060050040,
    "version" : 1.0
  },
  "Reading" : [
    {
      "id" : 54321,
      "units" : "fps",
      "data" : [
        {
          "value"  : 32,
          "time" : 1630000000000000400
        },
        {
          "value"  : 32,
          "time" : 1630000000000000400
        },
        {
          "value"  : 32,
          "time" : 1630000000000000400
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id" : 765432,
      "units" : "fps",
      "data" : [
        {
          "value"  : 21,
          "time" : 1630000000000000400
        },
        {
          "value"  : 21,
          "time" : 1630000000000000400
        },
        {
          "value"  : 21,
          "time" : 1630000000000000400
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is memory inefficent due to the ReadToEndAsync()**

```
using (var stream = _readFile(inFilePath)) //TODO Read async 
    {
        if (stream == null || stream == StreamReader.Null)
        {
            throw new Exception("streamReader is null");
        }
        
        data = JObject.Parse(await stream.ReadToEndAsync());
    }
}
```

**Where im stuck**

```
var memoryStream = UnTarGz.ExtractTarGzToStream(inFilePath);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            var header = new Header();
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken.None))
            { 
                //if somehow I can detect header set parameter above as header data. 
                //else if its reading data build an object such that 
                // {
                //     header = header;
                //     readings = the reading data
                // }
                //
                // add to queue
            }
                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `JsonSerializer` can still be fed a reader to deserialize a single object, you don't need to parse *everything* manually. So you'll get `StartObject`, `PropertyName` (`header`), then you can deserialize a `Header`, and so on. You can either chain these `Read` calls manually (anticipating the structure as-is), or write a little state machine and use a `switch`.

Comment: I don' t understand what are you trying. It will take the same memory, if you parce it chunk by chank or the whole peace. It is much easier to create smaller peaces in the begining of the pipe, when you are creating the text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeroen provided an overview of the solution in the comments. At the time of writing my reputation is about 5% of his, so it took me a while to figure out what that actually meant :) but as I finally got it working I'll post the result here in case this is what you're looking for:

```
public static class Json
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\input.json")) // This is your sample.
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var readingCounter = 0;

            // While there are tokens to be read, do it and update reader with token attributes.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject && reader.Path == "Header")
                {
                    var header = serializer.Deserialize<Header>(reader);
                    Console.WriteLine(header);
                }

                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject && reader.Path == $"Reading[{readingCounter}]")
                {
                    var currentReading = serializer.Deserialize<Reading>(reader);
                    readingCounter++;

                    // Process current reading object here (ex. "add to queue"):
                    Console.WriteLine(currentReading);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Header
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Datetime { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    // For the example only:
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + ", " + Datetime + ", " + Version;
    }
}

public class Reading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public List<ValueTime> Data { get; set; }

    // For the example only:
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + ", " + Units + ", data count = " + Data.Count;
    }
}

public class ValueTime
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
}
```